# How to fix "Show scroll bars" system preference being ignored?

Tags: trackpad, system-settings, macos

macOS General System Preferences contains this option:

[image]

When I select "Automatically based on mouse or trackpad", the behavior is identical to "Always". Scrollbars are always shown, no matter what. I do not use a mouse, I don't even own one! I only use the built-in trackpad.

I am not quite sure when this stopped working, and only noticed that this setting was ignored today. Restarting does not seem to affect the issue, and checking the setting from the terminal reports the correct value:

```
➜  ~ defaults read -g AppleShowScrollBars
Automatic
```

My model and macOS version can be seen here:

[image]

How can I get macOS to respect this setting?

Comment: Scrollbars are always shown system-wide, or in a particular application or applications?

Comment: Great question. This is system-wide. I see this behavior in the macOS Finder, macOS Messages, Chrome, and Safari. The only apps I don't see this in are ones that use custom scrollbars and don't respect this setting under any circumstances.